# Zabbix sensor 'no data'

Tags: zabbix, linuxmint

I'm having problems with monitoring my GPU temperature.

There's list of my sensors: `sensors -u`

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:
  temp1_input: 65.500
  temp1_crit: 99.000

...

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:
  temp1_input: 65.000
  temp1_max: 86.000
  temp1_crit: 100.000
  temp1_crit_alarm: 0.000

...
```

I've created application temperature with two keys:

- `sensor[coretemp-isa-0000,temp3]` for monitoring CPU, which works well
- `sensor[acpitz-virtual-0,temp1]` for monitoring GPU, which doesn't collect any data.

`CPU temperature` shows in `Monitoring -> Latest Data` section and it's data is avaliable in the graphs, whereas `GPU temperature` is absent in mentioned section and instead of statistics I see `[no data]` note below chart.

I have no idea why it's not working, because `zabbix_get -s 127.0.0.1 -k sensor[acpitz-virtual-0,temp1]` gives me nice output: `61.500000`.

I've also tried to increase `StartHTTPPollers` in `zabbix_server.conf`, but it didn't help.

All I've found in [zabbix_server.log](http://pastebin.com/RTyn0j2X) and [zabbix_agent.log](http://pastebin.com/LAmVSYeL) is:

```
13919:20150901:231222.255 item [Zabbix server:sensor[acpitz-virtual-0,temp1]] became not supported: Received value [61.5] is not suitable for value type [Numeric (unsigned)] and data type [Decimal]
```

I've changed both fields from `Decimal` to `Float`, but CPU still works and GPU still doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I don't know what more could happened, but I've just removed `GPU temperature` item and created it again using `copy` button from working `CPU temperature` item with `Numeric (float)` option type of information.

I don't know if it needed some time to start working or did I overlook something...

Comment: In "Administration" -> "General" -> "Other" there is "Refresh unsupported items (in sec)" setting, which is 10 minutes by default. It might be that you have not waited long enough. Also, StartHTTPPollers setting in zabbix_server.conf is for Web scenarios. For passive Zabbix agent items, you may only need to adjust StartPollers and StartPollersUnreachable.